# search in four files to see if the id is in there

Tags: python, file

[image]

i have one csv file and three text files. i have ids in my csv file and i want to know if they are in any of those text files. If it is in any of those files. I want it to print the csv id with the  line that id was found in the other files. And the file name it was found in and line it was found in the text file.

```
with open('SY.csv', 'r') as file1, open('SA.txt', as file2:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file1)
    for line in csv_reader:
        for row in file 2:
        words = row.split()
            if line['ID'] in words:
                print(line['ID']'  ' words[row])
```

Output

```
ID:6523   The computer ID:6523 File name:file 1 line: 1
    The laptop ID:6523 File name:file 2 line: 3
```

Comment: Please include content, not pictures of content. Actual content give people a chance to reproduce you problem.

Also, layout your code and output using the suggested markup in future.

Comment: How is your data formated in the text files? Are they just ID's separated by line breaks?

Comment: OK, I see code, I see desired output.  I don't see exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to use a regular expression to search the whole line instead of just breaking up the words

Comment: how do it get it to print the line where the id was found on and how do i print the name of the file it was found in

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pythons regular expression operations to [search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to for the ideas within the text files, depending on the size of them you can do this either line by line, or all at once by reading the file into memory.

```
file_contents = open('file 1', 'r').read()
with open('SY.csv', 'r') as input_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(input_csv)
    for line in reader:
       match = re.search(r'^.*' + line[0] + '.*', file_contents)
       if match:
           print match.group(0)
```

Comment: i want it to print the whole line and the line number it was found in AND DOES THIS PRINT THE FILE NAME

Comment: The regex will match the entire line, but currently does not print the file name, but that is easy enough to add.